# CSS - Printing Web Page at 50% scale by default

Tags: css, printing

Does anyone know if there is a way to have any webpage on our website to be defaulted to scale at 50% when someone tries printing from the browser? Or do I need to go in and create @print styles for printing?

Everything looks perfect at 50% but for some reason scaled at 100% looks like the browser is trying to force a mobile view.

Website is [VolleyballUSA.com](https://www.volleyballusa.com/professional-pole-pad/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a stylesheet for printing and add that to your page with a separate `<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css">`. Now you have full control over how things are rendered when sent to the printer by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you ARE getting the mobile view when printing (at least the containers in the middle are stacked instead of next to each other), that's simply due to the size of the page.

But you can change your media queries to only apply to screen (and not to printed media) using `@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)` and similar, with "only screen"  being the important keyword.

Comment: Just for clarification, you mean by adding the "only screen" portion to all my media queries, printed media shouldnt be affected anymore and there will be a more "normal" layout when me or a potential customer decides to print a web page from our website?

Comment: At least the media queries won't apply to print anymore - I haven't looked through all your stylesheets...

Answer (score 0):

Create a stylesheet for printing and add that to your page with a separate link element for printing purposes:

```
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="page.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css">
...
```

Now you have full control over how things are rendered when sent to the printer by the browser.

The `media` property is pretty useful, more details for it can be found over on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40media